# What does the phrase "at pace" mean?

Tags: meaning

It is from this [article](https://www.bbc.com/sport/boxing/46662371) about a boxing match.

> The rematch was again played out **at pace**, with Whyte picking smart shots under pressure.

I would get if there were a clarification of at what pace, slow or fast. Perhaps it has a somewhat different meaning there.

Comment: I believe the key is in the previous sentence, which you’ve omitted: _Whyte seemed more cautious than during **their heavy-hitting meeting in 2016** when he shaded a points win after 12 thrilling rounds which left many fans calling for a repeat._ It looks like a hastily-written article, probably submitted just moments after the fight as a sports journalist hurried to meet his deadline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Punches were traded or made rather quickly.

[Compare](https://www.sdlegion.com/team/jasa-veremalua/):

> The San Diego Legion will also benefit in 2019 from Fijian rugby union player and Olympic Sevens gold medalist Jasa Veremalua who’s [sic] speed and precision offloads ensures [sic]  a game played at pace.

[or](https://www.soccercoachweekly.net/soccer-drills-and-skills/midfield/run-games-like-paul-pogba/)

> This session centres on Paul Pogba running the game for his team and getting points for assists and for scoring goals – it’s a fast game, played at pace and will give your players a good test.

[or](http://www.warwickschoolsports.org/pu_MatchReport.asp?ID=258&FID=430440)

> Warwick played at pace from the off and never gave the visitors a chance to settle...

Comment: Look here https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pace at the meaning d(1) as a noun. While commonly associated with speed, 'pace' can also refer to tempo, i.e. the frequency of events happening, e.g. punches thrown per minute.

Comment: @Ross Murray But here Whyte is "under pressure".  In a boxing match, you're under pressure when the punches are coming your way in rather quick succession, not slow and steady at an even, measured tempo. .."

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot get it. Does "at pace" mean "keep up the current pace"?

Comment: @Dmytro O'Hope: **At pace** means "at a rather brisk tempo".  "It's a fast game, played at pace".  I have no idea where you're getting an imperative construction from it, "keep up".

Comment: In my job specification: "experienced in delivery of service improvements at pace",

Comment: I didn't mean it in imperative, I meant "keeping up"

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope  Do you understand what the following means?  "Chess is often played *at a slow pace*, with a single game taking up to six hours".

Comment: Yes, I understand that

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope And do you understand the following?  "You must act *with speed* or you will miss the deadline"

Comment: You are right. I understand that too

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope  Do you understand how with old vinyl recordings that were played on a record player with a tone-arm at the end of which there was a needle, that there were three speeds?   33RPM, 45RPM, and 78RPM, and that "33RPM" was a relatively *slow speed* and 78RPM was a relatively *fast speed*?

Comment: I didn't have that type of music player, so it is difficult to me to get what mean by that

Comment: Could you please clear that up?

Comment: RPM = revolutions per minute. The platter spins, and the device can be told at which speed the platter should spin, 33 RPM, 45 RPM, or 78 RPM.  Now do you understand?  There are three different **speeds**. My point is that you should not be confused by the phrase "slow speed" even though "act *with speed*" from my earlier comment means "fast", not "with some unknown speed".

Comment: And just as "with speed" can mean "fast", so too can "at pace" mean "fast".